# Jenkins: Cannot connect slave to master

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins on a linux server and I want to set up slave on windows virtual machine.

I created simple slave node, with launch method: JNLP.

There is no firewall on the windows machine.

I can connect both via ssh, also I can connect from linux to windows on port 52263 and from windows to linux on port 135.

Still when I try to launch the slave, it cannot be connected.

What should I check? Where could be the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Then I try to connect windows slave I have to open ports at Linux firewall and set static TCP port for JNLP agents at http://jenkinsurl:8080/configureSecurity/

Also you can see extra errors at windows java console.

Answer (score -1):

Choose "Launch Method as Launch agent via Java Web Start" and provide proper "Remote root directory". For more information, please go through https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines

Comment: Hi, what is this directory? I did set it up like in the tutorial C:\Jenkins but this is just an empty directory.